# How to solve two correlated SDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Les's say we have SDEs:
$$\begin{aligned} 
dX=&f(X,t)dt+h(X,t)dw;\\ 
dY=&p(X,t)dt+q(X,t)dw.
\end{aligned}
$$

How can we represent $Y$ without the explicit dependence to $X$ like:
$$
dY=m(Y,t)dt+n(Y,t)dw.
$$

Edit:

1. I try to represent an intermediate variable $S(t)=\int_0^tp(X,s)ds$ and insert it into the SDE for $Y$. This gives back a very complicated SDE including both differential and integral terms.
2. I am aware that this can be represent as a vector SED with scalar noise:
   $$dK=A(K,t)dt+B(K,t)dW,$$ with $K=[X,Y]$ being a vector, $A,B$ being a matrix. and $dW$ being a scalar noise. We can solve this SDE using numeric methods.

However, I still want to know that if there is any analytical method to simplify this problem first.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Could the statistics stack exchange attract a bit more relevant answers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in most cases.  For example, if $q = f \equiv 0$ and $h = p \equiv 1$, then $X_t = W_t$ and $Y_t = \int_0^t W_s ds$.  Then $Y$ is not a Markov process.

However, if there were $m,n$ such that $dY_t = m(Y_t,t)dt + n(Y_t,t)dW_t$, we would have $Y$ is an Ito diffusion, and in particular a Markov process.  Thus no such $m$ and $n$ can exist.

Comment: Yeah, i got it. Does this mean that we can only numerically solve the problem as described before (for both Ito and stratonovich form)?

Comment: @BenjaminJiang It depends on what you mean by "solve the problem."  In the example I gave, I would consider $Y_t = \int_0^t W_s ds$ to be analytically solved, even if it isn't really a closed form.